# Receive delivery error for failed delivery with Mailgun SMTP

Tags: mailgun

Currently, when I send mail from Mailgun SMTP, and it is not delivered, message is silently dropped and trace about it appear only in logs. It is possible to receive delivery notes when delivery failed, as in standard email accounts? (delivery notes like: `This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification. Delivery to the following recipie...` and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all failed mail to the mailgun by this API:

```
RestClient.get("https://api:YOUR-API-KEY"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR-DOMAIN/events",
   :params => {
    :'begin'       => 'Fri, 3 May 2013 09:00:00 -0000',
    :'ascending'   => 'yes',
    :'limit'       =>  25,
    :'pretty'      => 'yes',
    :'event'       => 'failed'
   }){|response, request, result| response }
```